# Appengine Entity's fully specified key

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Entity's method `getKey()` states:

> Returns the Key that represents this Entity. If the entity has not yet
>   been saved (e.g. via DatastoreService.put), this Key will not be fully
>   specified and cannot be used for certain operations (like
>   DatastoreService.get). Once the Entity has been saved, its Key will be
>   updated to be fully specified.

What does the **fully specified** mean?

In following test, keys are the same before and after `DatastoreService#put(Entity)`:

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity e = new Entity("Person", "John");

System.out.println(e.getKey()); // output: Person("John")
System.out.println(KeyFactory.keyToString(e.getKey())); // output: aglub19hcHBfaWRyEAsSBlBlcnNvbiIESm9obgw

Key k = ds.put(e);

System.out.println(k); // output: Person("John")
System.out.println(KeyFactory.keyToString(k)); // output: aglub19hcHBfaWRyEAsSBlBlcnNvbiIESm9obgw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an ambiguity in the documentation. Instead of "will not be fully specified and cannot be used for certain operations" it should say "*may* not be fully specified and *may* not be used for certain operations".

When you created an entity, you provided all the information necessary to create a fully specified key: entity kind ("Person") and an identifier ("John"). This passage from the documentation applies to situations when you only specify an entity kind, in which case the identifier will be auto-generated by the Datastore when the entity is saved. Without this identifier the key cannot be used for a `get` operation.